# Placing Images in aSimple Webpage

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am very new to HTML and CSS. I am creating a page I will insert it into my Wordpress website thoughtprojekt.com. I tried every where else to achieve what I am trying to but couldn't.

There is a header that I coded is below which is fine.

```
p.h1{
padding-top:75px; 
padding-bottom: 25px;
}

a.header{
text-transform: uppercase;
text-align: center; 
font-weight: normal;
text-decoration: none;
display:block;
color: #000000;
font-size:50px;
font-family: 'Lato Light', sans-serif;
line-height:50px;
letter-spacing:15px;
}
</style>

</head>
<p class ="h1" align="center">&nbsp;<body><a class="header" href="http://thoughtprojekt.com">Thought Projekt</font></a>
```

Now I want to place 64px x 64px (30 images) starting exactly in the center and right below "Thought Projekt". There should be only 5 images in a row with 6 rows in total. I have tried padding but as the images also have hyperlinks it leaves clickable blank spaces.

Can someone please guide me as to how should I start placing the images?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use divs to set limits, for a row **width**.
And, for **float** the items, where you put the images...

[Example](https://jsbin.com/zukiqo/edit?html,css,output)

html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="image"><img src="#" alt="Image"/></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.row {
  max-width: 340px;
}

.image{
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. However, how can I efficiently bring the whole box of the images in center? I tried using `padding-left: 300px; but I feel this isn't the most apt way. Any suggestion there? Many thanks.

Comment: To center an element you can use `margin: auto` or any other CSS method. if you want to learn more ways to do it right, I suggest you to checkout [this tool](http://howtocenterincss.com/) and also read about _flexbox_

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is that you need to make a whole div where all the images will go in. Withing that div, you will place 6 div's one below the other and within each div, you place each image next to each other.

The HTML code will look like this:

```
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="images.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <img src="your_image.png">
        <img src="your_image.png">
        <img src="your_image.png">
        <img src="your_image.png">
        <img src="your_image.png">
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <img src="your_image.png">
        <img src="your_image.png">
        <img src="your_image.png">
        <img src="your_image.png">
        <img src="your_image.png">
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <img src="your_image.png">
        <img src="your_image.png">
        <img src="your_image.png">
        <img src="your_image.png">
        <img src="your_image.png">
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <img src="your_image.png">
        <img src="your_image.png">
        <img src="your_image.png">
        <img src="your_image.png">
        <img src="your_image.png">
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <img src="your_image.png">
        <img src="your_image.png">
        <img src="your_image.png">
        <img src="your_image.png">
        <img src="your_image.png">
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <img src="your_image.png">
        <img src="your_image.png">
        <img src="your_image.png">
        <img src="your_image.png">
        <img src="your_image.png">
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Then for CSS:

```
//This is the images.css file located in the same folder with html file
.container .row img{
  float: left;    //Each image will be next ot each other
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}

.row{
  display: block;
  height: 64px;
}

.container{
    width: 320px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    margin: auto 0px;
    float: right;
}
```

I believe this is what you are asking for. Hope it helps!

PS: Are you new to stackoverflow? Welcome! :)

Comment: Yes I am new to stackoverflow GeorGios :) I am trying with your suggestion.